# joomla plugin yoogallery not working in category blog layout

Tags: php, joomla, gallery, joomla1.5

I installed the yoogallery plugin and inserted this into my articles:
{yoogallery src=[/images/stories/inscheping/]}

this works fine when I open the article like this:
set.com/nl/nieuws/1-inscheping

but when I open my category blog layout (site.com/nl/nieuws), I can't see the images but I just see this text:
{yoogallery src=[/images/stories/inscheping/]}

What can be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the module isn't loaded in an article
I got this plugin now, modules in articles and it works just fine